# Java compile source level higher than target level

Tags: java

Does the Java compiler work well if using a target level lower than the source level? For example:

```
javac -source 1.7 -target 1.6
```

Comment: And what happened when you tried it?

Comment: If it compiles it should run.

Comment: **[javac] javac: source release 1.7 requires target release 1.7**

Comment: I do not agree with the duplicate mark. That one is only focused on Intellij, but doesn't tell us any reason.

Answer (score -2, accepted):

if you compiler code use java 1.7,the code can not run with java 1.6,if you do this,you will receive a Unsupported major.minor version.

Comment: Err, yes it can, if it compiles and you use the -target 1.6 switch, which is what the question is about.

Comment: I've just tried for modern source level 1.8 with bytecode target version 1.7 but it failed:
**[javac] javac: source release 1.8 requires target release 1.8**

Comment: @Splash Any idea why that happens? I thought that it should be possible to set the target lower than the source level, but apparently that's not the case. Can't find any good reference.

Comment: Maybe they are too lazy to implement all new features of Java 8 using old 7 version internal mechanic.